# How to circumvent shortcutting of `||`

Tags: java

I have two methods `boolean foo1()` and `boolean foo2()`. If at least one of these is `true` then I need to call `save()`. But I need both functions to run.

If I write `if (foo1() || foo2()) {save()}` then `foo2()` will not run due to the way `||` works.

Currently I write

```
boolean f1 = foo1();
boolean f2 = foo2();

if (f1 || f2) {save()}
```

but this is not very elegant.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: *"this is not very elegant"* I disagree. It's very clear about your intent. Clarity beats line count every time. If you use `if (foo1() | foo2()) { save(); }` it looks like a typo, and obscures the importance of ensuring you call both functions.

Comment: relying on `|` not being a short cut operator could be a surprising usage. It suggest there are side effects of `foo2()` which it is not clear that you need from reading this code.  I think you should do that you have above to make it clear what you trying to achieve.  The difference between `|` and `||` is easy to miss (as you may have done)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder snap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `|` operator (See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)):

```
if (f1 | f2) { }
```

Note that the same applies for `&`. For example, if you write:

```
if (returnFalse() & returnTrue()) {
    destroyTheWorld();
}
```

Then both methods will run, but the world is safe.

Note that a programmer who's not familiar with the `|` operator might think it's a typo and might add another pipe to it. Make sure to well document it, or simple:

```
f1 = method1();
f2 = method2();

if (f1 || f2) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: @P45Imminent: Be sure to comment it or something, because otherwise it looks like a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed missing something obvious.

Use `|` rather than `||`.

The former *always* evaluates both arguments and works well for `boolean` types. But it is not particularly idiomatic - and is therefore vulnerable to alteration by an overenthusiastic refactorer - so I'd recommend your using a comment, or perhaps retaining your so-called inelegant code as that does offer you implicit clarity that my flashy solution lacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bitwise operator: `|`.

This will guarantee both terms are evaluated, hence both methods executed in your case.

`if (foo1() | foo2()) {save()}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `|` operator.

Just do:

```
if (f1 | f2) {save()}
```